# What is better to use when testing a web application that uses EF Core, 'Mock', or 'InMemory'?

Tags: c#, .net-core

There is a web application (.NET Core 3.1) that uses a MySql database using EF Core. There is a class in the application (ControlDataBase) that is responsible for executing the request via EF Core and returns data to the main method (ConnectUser). As a result, when I wanted to test the main method (ConnectUser), I thought that I should write Mock for ORM, but in sites said that this makes no sense and it is better to use InMemory at all. As a result, who better knows how to write Mock EF Core or will it be enough to use ImMemory for testing?

Example:

```cs
ActionResul ConnectUser(){ 
    var idUser = ControlDataBase.GetUserId(dataUser.Login);
}

string GetUserId(string login) { 
    return db.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(user => user.Login.Equals(login));
}
```

Comment: Can to be more specific about what you mean by `better`? What specific feature of both you want to compare? Otherwise question will remain opinion based and probably will be closed soon

Comment: That is, what is better in testing to use when using ORM. Mock OR or In Memory?

Comment: More precisely, what will be practical and effective?

Comment: Different people look for different things when talking about pragmatism and effectiveness. One will use In-Memory and treat DbContext as black box (but will pay some price because DbContext with In-Memory provider is not fully similar as DbContext with actual database provider). Another will mock DbContext because want to be sure that concrete methods being called with expected arguments. So there are no one better or worth, but both approaches serve different purposes - such tradeoff you should decide by itself or your team.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad you took the time to answer my question.